# What is the state of the art in fast implementation techniques for modular exponentiation?

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate ($m^{e} \pmod{N}$) in `C` or `C++`. I want to use 2048 bits long modulus $N$ and thus the above process of exponentiation will use a huge amount of calculations and time. **I want to know the possible optimizations I can use**.

I particularly came across this :

Converting the exponent to its binary bit pattern and then looping from MSB to LSB, calculating the square of the result at each step mod N and if the present bit of exponent is 1, multiplying the result by m.

Also, I can compute the square of the result using the Karatsuba algorithm.

What other optimizations, if possible, exists in this regard?

**Is there any already implemented and optimized library for C or C++ for such type of modular arithmetic?**

Comment: related [Efficient function/algorithm/method to do modular exponentiation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75408/18298), also [how to iteratively calculate a^emod n with modulus n sized 4096 bits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10691/18298)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Agreed!! Changed the title. RSA was really irrelevant to this question.

Comment: A reasonable cheap constant-time approach is fixed-window exponentiation with Montgomery multiplication, with table lookup by arithmetic.  Faster—but leakier—approaches involve sliding windows.  A standard reference for these can be found in Menezes, van Oorschot, and Vanstone's [_Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).  For modern implementation with side channel defenses, consider reviewing what BearSSL does.

Comment: If you know the factors of $N$, then you can also use the Chinese remainder theorem, so it matters whether you're talking about the public-key operation or the private-key operation.  For the public-key operation, you just can pick $e = 3$ so it's a single squaring plus a single multiplication, as long as you use the primitive in a serious cryptosystem like RSA-KEM or RSA-PSS (and _not_ ‘textbook RSA’).

Comment: "Is there already a library to do this" - "yes, BearSSL / BoringSSL and their leakier competitors" which is strictly speaking a request for a software recommendation and thus off-topic. Asking for efficient, naturally side-channel resistant algorithms on the other hand is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @kelalaka FYI, mpz_* is a bad idea for cryptography because gmp automatically truncates mpz objects according to their most significant bit, which leaks the position of the most significant bit by timing, which is a popular attack vector these days: https://minerva.crocs.fi.muni.cz, http://tpm.fail.  You should use mpn_* instead.  (Why gmp even provides mpz_powm_sec is a mystery to me.)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage [Here](https://gmplib.org/devel/sec.html) they say that `mpz_powm_sec` function, supported by a corresponding `mpn_sec_powm` and `mpn_cnd_sub_n`

Comment: It looks like these days, OpenSSL, gmp, and BearSSL all use essentially what I described: fixed-window exponentiation with Montgomery multiplication.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, I know, but mpz_powm_sec still has the msb side channel.  You shouldn't use mpz_* at all for secrets.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I suppose if you wanted to try hard enough you could probably also use addition chain exponentiation (14.98 in the handbook of applied crypto) and use 3-4 primes for RSA with the carmichael instead of the euler-phi function.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Thanks a lot! It will be used in the Private key  operations so the exponents are going to be large.  I will have a look at the Handbook of Applied Cryptography.