# RSA Cryptosytsem, choosing $e$

Tags: rsa

I am using the RSA crytposytem. I have $p$, $q$ and hence $n$ and $\phi$ however I don't understand how to get $e$ such that $gcd(e,\phi)=1$

Many thanks

Comment: That's covered [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20328/555).

Comment: @fgrieu Should we hit the close button?

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose e such that it is co-prime relative to PHY(n). Since you do not want to get involved in factorization of PHY(n), the best way is to choose e randomly, and better let it be a non even prime. Common values are 2^16+1, 3, etc. Most of the primes you choose will have GCD(e,PHY(n))=1.