# Is RSA-OAEP secure when e=3?

Tags: rsa, oaep

Is RSA-OAEP secure when the exponent is equal to 3?

Comment: See also [What security authorities and standards reject e=3 in RSA, when, and with what rationale?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/what-security-authorities-and-standards-reject-e-3-in-rsa-when-and-with-what)