# Relationship between exponent and modulus in RSA (as RSA properties as listed in X.509)

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

In one of my assignments, I had the following question (Please read on. Not a homework assignment :) ):

> X.509 (1998 version) lists properties that RSA keys must satisfy to be
>   secure. One such requirement is that the public exponent  $e > \log_2(n)$ where n is the modulus. Consider the
>   following justifications for this:
>
> 1. We require $e > \log_2(n)$ in order to prevent an attack to disclose the plaintext by taking the *eth root modulus
>      n*.
> 2. We require $e > \log_2(n)$ in order to prevent an attack to disclose the plaintext by taking the *eth integer root*.
>
> Which of these two is the correct justification of the above
>   requirement? For the incorrect justification, explain why is it
>   incorrect.

My question here is: Where is the X.509 certificate listed mentioning the above requirement? I tried googling a lot but could not find any such requirement listed in any  online available material unfortunately.
Also, if any such requirement does exist, what is the justification for the same?

Comment: X.509 is a standard for certificates. The original specification appears to have had a "security considerations" section discussing these requirements. An X.509 certificate is any certificate that follows the X.509 specification. As for the justification, imagine what happens if you encrypt $2$ using $e$ if $e<\log_2(n)$ using textbook RSA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirement was introduced in [IUT Recommendation X.509 (November 1993)](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.509-199311-S!!PDF-E&type=items), informative appendix D.5.2:

> It must be ensured that e > log<sub>2</sub>(n). If not, then the simple operation of taking the integer e<sup>th</sup> root of a ciphertext block will disclose the plaintext.

This advice was removed in the 2000 edition of the standard. It was [arguably misguided](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8469/555), and at the very least the justification given was very incorrect (even when using RSA for encryption without padding, what's stated in the justification works only for a very small portion of plaintexts, including for $e=3$; it thus does not work at all for random plaintext, or when using RSA with proper padding).

The assignment itself is questionable: we are asked to choose among two incorrect justifications for advice so questionable that it was removed; and it turns out that the few plaintexts allowing the attack in 1 to work also allow to perform precisely what's claimed in 2. The only superiority of argument 1 is that it more clearly describes an attack which is NOT a good reason to use a public exponent larger than some bound.