# Bleichenbacher's Attack on high public exponent RSA keys?

Tags: encryption, rsa, attack

Why can't Bleichenbacher's Attack work for RSA public exponents with values equal to 65537 and above? Does the fact that 65337 is a prime number have any relevance to it?

Answer (score 5):

Some attacks on some ad-hoc RSA encryption or signature padding, or/and their defective implementation, including several attacks due to Daniel Bleichenbacher, require an RSA public exponents $e$ of small value.

The limit has to do with some part of the padding (including a hash of $h$ bits), raised to the $e^\text{th}$ power, not being much wider than the public modulus $N$ of $n$ bits. It follows that $e\gg n/h$ block *these* attacks (but far from all attacks on ad-hoc RSA padding). There is no relation to $e$ being prime.

In RSA, ad-hoc padding should thus be avoided in favor of padding with reducibility to the RSA problem (like RSAES-OAEP, RSASSA-PSS, ISO/IEC 9796-2 mode 2 or 3), or schemes that do not need padding (like RSA-KEM). Security authorities recommend that for new applications, and $e\ge65537$ everywhere; see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8454/555) for more.

---

**Digression: Why 65537?**

Using prime RSA public exponent $e$ is customary: it makes drawing randomly seeded primes $p$ with $\gcd(p-1,e)=1$ (as required in RSA) easier and less subject to implementation goofs.

Using $e$ of the form $2^k+1$ is customary: raising to such $e^\text{th}$ power reduces to squaring $k$ times, then multiplying once by the original number (including for operations modulo $N$ as in RSA).

Primes of the form $2^k+1$ are thus customary. They demonstrably all are with $k$ a power of two, and known as [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). With $h\ge128$ and $n\le16384$ in most practical uses of RSA, using for $e$ the fifth (and largest known or practically usable) Fermat prime $F_4=2^{(2^4)}+1=65537$ is always very much on the safe side w.r.t. matching $e\gg n/h$.

Comment: Trying different values for $e$ didn't produce any noticeable slowdown using the default Java RSA implementation, so it may be common to chose F4 but in real life the expected speedup may be non-existent. By now it is just a sensible default, I guess.

Comment: Are you measuring the public-key operation or the private-key operation?  The performance of the private-key operation is independent of the public exponent (unless you _choose_ a small private exponent and derive the public one from that, but that's a bad idea).  The performance of the public-key operation is $(\text{cost of $|n|$-bit squaring})\cdot\log_2 e + (\text{cost of $|n|$-bit multiply})\cdot\operatorname{Hamming-Weight}(e)$.  It is usually quite easy to measure the difference in public-key operations between $e = 3$ and $e = 65537$: the latter is approximately fifteen times slower.

Comment: @fgrieu: Don't forget the much simpler, faster, safer schemes RSA-FDH and RSA-KEM!

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage: The difference in RSA public-key function timing between $e=65537$ and $e=3$ is usually by about a factor slightly below $(16+1)/(1+1)$ (that is like eight, not _"fifteen"_), often less for implementations using Montgomery arithmetic or DPA countermeasures (the later makes sense for encryption, and the former allows code reuse). I'm seeing RSA-FDH as a design principle for deterministic RSA signature schemes, prescribing to use a public hash into $\mathbb Z_N$. Is there a specification for RSA-FDH, in the sense that it allows implementations to inter-operate?

Comment: @fgrieu: 15 is just a couple off-by-one errors away from 8 in that formula, and as we all know, there are only two hard problems in computing: naming, cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors!  As for RSA-FDH, I'm not aware of a standard, but, _e.g._, djb's Rabin–Williams instantiation uses a prescribed hash function, and you could trivially instantiate it with SHAKE256.