# Problem with brainpool?

Tags: elliptic-curves

In the [GnuPG 2.1 release notes](https://www.gnupg.org/(it)/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html), there is this phrase:

> For many people the NIST and also the Brainpool curves have an doubtful origin

I've read elsewhere that people have doubts about the NIST curves, but I've never heard anything disparaging about the Brainpool curves. What could the release notes be referring to?

Comment: There's great overlap with [Choice of ECC curve on usb token](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60392/choice-of-ecc-curve-on-usb-token). I guess the present question can be merged with that other.