# Picking 'e' for RSA encryption

Tags: rsa, keys

What is the reason behind picking either $3$ or $2^{16}+1$ for generating the public key in RSA?

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8454/54184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of computing $x^e \bmod n$, which is the bottleneck in any RSA-based cryptosystem, is $\lfloor\log_2 e\rfloor$ squarings and $H(e) - 1$ multiplications modulo $n$, where $H$ is Hamming weight.<sup>*</sup>  Since $e$ is required to be coprime with $\operatorname{lcm}(p - 1, q - 1)$, the most efficient possible choice is $e = 3$.<sup>†</sup>

Originally, the 1977 RSA proposal (which was broken by modern standards in several ways, even ignoring parameter sizes) was to choose $d$ at random and derive $e$ from it.  But there's no security advantage to that, and it's much cheaper to choose $e$ to be small.

Historical RSA-based cryptosystems were badly designed and failed to provide meaningful security: if you naively try to encrypt a message $m$ like a 256-bit secret key by computing $m^e \bmod n$, and $e = 3$, and $\log_2 n > 768$, then it turns out $m^e \bmod n$ is just the *integer* cube of $m$ and an attacker can recover $m$ from $m^3$ just by computing integer (*i.e.*, real number) cube roots.

So, in an attempt to stem the bleeding of such painfully naive use of RSA like this, people started using bigger exponents like $F_4 = 2^{16} + 1 = 65537$, despite the additional cost it imposes.

The sensible thing to do would be to choose $x$ at random, use a hash of $x$ as a secret key for an authenticated cipher, and transmit $x^3 \bmod n$ alongside the ciphertext—we call this RSA-KEM today.  But because of the decades of RSA abuse, people developed PTSD about small exponents with RSA, and some still break out in a cold sweat when you mention any exponent smaller than 65537.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> For certain exponents the cost may be a little lower with an appropriate choice of Lucas chain, but when $H(e) = 2$ as in $e = 3$ or $e = 2^{16} + 1$ there's not much improvement to be had over the naive square-and-multiply algorithm.</sub>

<sub><sup>†</sup> Rabin-type cryptosystems use modular squaring, or ‘$e = 2$’, but they are qualitatively different from RSA-type cryptosystems.</sub>

Comment: minor comment: a naive left-to-right square and multiply will costs $H(e)-1$ multiplications. e.g. for e=3, $H(e)=2$ but you you do $b^2*b$

Comment: @Ruggero One of those two hardest things in computing—naming, cache invalidation, and fenceposts!

Comment: What you mean by ~ squarings "and" H(e)-1? Do you mean that they are two different representations of the 'cost'?

Comment: $\lfloor\log_2 e\rfloor$ squarings, and $H(e) - 1$ multiplications—squarings are usually slightly cheaper than multiplications, but each one is more or less quadratic in $\log n$.  The particular choice of cost model varies depending on whom you talk to; popular choices are the RAM metric, the NAND metric, and the AT or area\*time metric, the last of which most closely matches physical reality.  On a particular machine one might measure cost in CPU cycles, or in joules.