# RSA: exploiting consecutive primes

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring, multi-prime-rsa

It's given 2 plaintexts $m_1$ and $m_2$, and 5 different values of $n\quad\{n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5\}$ which are generated as follows:

- $n_1$ is a a product of two relatively small 128-bit $p$ and $q$ so its easily factorable by a simple database look-up,
- $n_2$ is the value of $p_1*p_2*q_1*q_2$, with $p_2$ being the next prime after a 512-bit prime $p_1$, and $q_2$ being the next prime after a 512-bit prime $q_1$
- $n_3$, $n_4$, $n_5$ each are product of two 1024-bit primes, but that shouldn't be an issue as we see later.

The encryption:

- $m_1$ is simply encrypted using $e = 65537$ with $n_2$, three times, giving $c_1$;
- $m_2$ is encrypted using $e=65537$ with $n_1$ and then $n_2$, generating $c_2$, which is not given;
- However, $c_2$ is then encrypted separately using $e=3$ with $n_3$, $n_4$, and $n_5$, giving $c_3, c_4$,and $c_5$ respectively.

So all the info we have now is $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, $n_4$, $n_5$, $c_1$, $c_3$, $c_4$, and $c_5$. A small public exponent attack should work for $n_3$, $n_4$, and $n_5$, and as said earlier $n_1$ is already factorable but the thing that brings trouble is $n_2$.

Fermat's factorization gives 2 non-primes close to each other which I assumed are $p_1*q_2$ and $p_2*q_1$ respectively. My reasoning was: since $p_2 = p_1 + k$ for some relatively small $k$ and $q_2 = q_1 + \ell$ for some relatively small $\ell$, cross-multiplying the two pairs must give two numbers that are near each other,

- is my hunch correct?
- how can I go forward from here?
- does the suspiciously low public exponent encryption of $n_3$, $n_4$, and $n_5$ have anything to do with factoring $n_2$?

Answer (score 1):

> $n_1$ is a product of two relatively small 128-bit $p$ and $q$ so its easily factorable by a simple database look-up

Hint: use an approximation of the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) to comfort or challenge that reasoning.

> A small public exponent attack should work for $n_3$, $n_4$, and $n_5$

Hint: $e=3$ is questionable if some conditions are met, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8454/555). You haven't stated which of these these conditions is met.

> Is my hunch (that Fermat factorization will reveal a non-trivial factorization of $n_2$) correct?

You've got a non-quantitative justification of that hunch, which correctly identifies the non-trivial factorization you can hope to get. To decide if that works, quantitatively estimate what's the expected number of steps in the Fermat method, or just try it.

> How can I go forward from here?

Hints valid for RSA-related CTFs: Write relations between unknowns as formulas. Estimate the expected bit size of unknowns. Try to identify a path towards a solution, as the sequence of unknowns to compute. Try to put all stated, testable, or probable facts to good use. Basic tools include algebra, the [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (plus, in some advanced cases, [Copersmith's theorem](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/lic13/lec04.pdf)). Show us your progress in the question if you hope for more hints.

> Does the suspiciously low public exponent encryption of $n_3$, $n_4$, and $n_5$ have anything to do with factoring $n_2$?

You don't present any argument towards this. And $e=3$ is not used in conjunction with $n_2$. On top of it, breaking poorly devised RSA encryption with whatever odd public exponent leads to factoring the modulus as a byproduct only when it's recovered a private exponent, or exploited the implementation, or the plaintext somewhat helps the factorization.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140870/discussion-on-answer-by-fgrieu-rsa-exploiting-consecutive-primes).