# RSA with small decryption exponent

Tags: rsa

I've heard that textbook RSA is insecure when decryption exponent $d$ is smaller than  $N^{1/4}$ where $N$ is the public modulus. Why is it the case and what would be  a simple explanation of the attack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA without proper padding using randomness (plain old RSA) is not to be used in practice, and the attacks on small exponents assume plain old RSA, or a means of getting past the padding, such as the so-called million message attack.

The original attack on plain old RSA using such small exponents was due to Wiener. There has been further work showing that an even larger $d$ than $d>N^{1/4}$ is required, such as work by [Maitra and Sarkar](http://eprint.iacr.org/2008/228.pdf).

In addition, please see the extensive discussion in the question [RSA with small exponents](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109/rsa-with-small-exponents?rq=1).

Comment: Is it possible for you to briefly outline the Wiener attack ?